# Multiple @font-face ignored in epub

Tags: html, css, fonts, epub

I am generating EPUB files with embedded fonts using `ebook-convert` from the calibre project. When I declare multiple font faces in HTML, it works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
font-family: "test";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
src: url(fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf);
}
@font-face{
font-family: "test";
font-style: italic;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
src: url(fonts/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf);
}
body{
font-family: "test";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This is a test with <i>italic</i>.
</body>
</html>
```

produces:

[image: fonts in HTML]

but when I convert it to EPUB, I only get the first font for the whole document:

[image: same code in the EPUB]

I checked the EPUB. The fonts are embedded properly and the CSS is included. There can't be a conflict with my system fonts since I used "test" as a string to identify the font.

What is wrong with EPUB? Am I declaring the fonts wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post about epub fonts](http://blog.threepress.org/2009/09/16/how-to-embed-fonts-in-epub-files/) may help

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid it's the only solution indeed…